# Pulse audio + Jack : some pulse audio apps work some don't

Tags: audio, pulseaudio, jack

Debian Buster. I use Pulseaudio as sound server but sometimes launch Jack for MAO.

When Jack is on, I can get the sound of Pulseaudio applications thanks to the pulseaudio-module-jack that adds a Pulseaudio sink to Jack (as I explained in https://askubuntu.com/a/1213554/419514).

Except I came to realize that not all applications work.

I do get the sound of vlc. But when using Firefox, Quodlibet or Audacity, nothing comes out. In fact, when clicking the "play" button, the cursor on the time slider doesn't even move. The "play" button indicates the file is playing but it is not. The playback begins as soon as I stop Jack.

I couldn't find any relevant log.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to open pavucontrol and set "Jack sink" as output for each application. Once this is set, it gets back to my soundcard when I stop jackd and it is automatically set back to "Jack sink" when I start it again.

Answer (score 0):

On the different systems I've worked with, Audacity tends to be the most flexible of DAWs. Try changing devices in Edit>Preferences. ALSA might be a safer bet than Jack.

Firefox is typically PulseAudio dependent.

One thing that might really help is to get Cadence from the [KXStudio repositories](https://kx.studio/Repositories).

Comment: Cadence is a python-based alternative to Qjackctl, giving you a graphical interface & allowing different ways of bridging ALSA & PulseAudio into Jack.

Comment: Sometimes the only solution is 'killall -9 jackd jackdbus', and then restart jack altogether.

Comment: Quodlibet and Audacity use ALSA as backend already and function correctly when jack is off. The point is that when jask is on, they should go through the pulse audio sink but they don't.

Comment: @Jérôme One cadence setting allows you to bridge ALSA audio through PulseAudio and then to JACK (Plugin). I think it's worth trying. Cadence works without installing (python script I think), just download and run. Did you try already?